# find similar value of an array object and calculate the sold

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi am trying to find similar value of this array object and calculate the some of sold for each same values

```
const sold = [
  { matri: 1, year: 2019, sold: 5 },
  { matri: 2, year: 2020, sold: 3 },
  { matri: 1, year: 2020, sold: 7 },
];
```

above i have one array object the expected output

```
{ matri: 1, year: 2020, sold: 5 },
{ matri: 1, year: 2020, sold: 7 },
```

sold: 5
+
sold: 7

output sold : 12

Comment: the year in the input is different but when you wrote the expected output, the year is 2020 for both entries. Does the year matters?

Comment: thanks but no years not matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to group and sum the `sold` property:

```js
const sold = [
  { matri: 1, year: 2019, sold: 5 },
  { matri: 2, year: 2020, sold: 3 },
  { matri: 1, year: 2020, sold: 7 },
];

const result = Object.values(sold.reduce((carry, entry) => {
  if (!carry.hasOwnProperty(entry.matri)) {
     carry[entry.matri] = {matri: entry.matri, sold: entry.sold};
  }
  else {
     carry[entry.matri].sold += entry.sold;
  }
  return carry;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i tried but i couldn't find similar